# How do I create nodes with comments enabled using drush?

Tags: drush

I have a drupal 9.1.5 site with a custom node type. I can create test content for it using drush by running;

`drush genc 1 --bundles=mynode --authors=test`

However, half of the content has comments disabled. I think what is happening is that drush is randomly settings the *COMMENT SETTINGS* field:

[image]

Drush has a `--skip-fields` parameter, but I don't know what to put in there. I've tried a bunch of different things like `field_mynode_comment` (the machine name of the field) but none seemed to work. I'm basically guessing.

How can I use drush to create nodes that always allow comments?

Comment: Did you try with devel generate ?

Comment: @miststudent2011 – `drush genc` is Devel Generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a workaround;

I can coerce all nodes to enable comments by running a query like this:

```
drush sql-query "UPDATE node__field_mynode_comment SET field_mynode_comment_status = 2"
```

I had a look at the database and found the `node__field_mynode_comment` table, which has a `field_mynode_comment_status` column. I found that the nodes with that column set to `2` had comments enabled, so I ran the above query to set it for all nodes, and now all nodes have comments enabled.

Incidentally I also tried creating the nodes with that field name ignored (`--skip-fields=field_mynode_comment_status`) but that didn't seem to have any effect.